# Как роутер определяет путь до ip-адреса назначения?

Tags: администрирование, ip, маршрутизация

Не пойму, как роутер понимает через какие еще маршрутизаторы нужно пройти пакету, чтобы добраться до требуемого IP-адреса? Т.е., например, отправляется запрос на открытие html-страницы с домашнего компьютера (через домашний роутер) в Волгограде на сайт, хостинг которого находится в Мексике. И как этот домашний роутер поймет, через какие из тясяч промежуточных роутеров нужно пропустить пакет, чтобы добраться до Мексики?

Comment: Для компьютера мак адрес, для роутеров `BSSID`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В маршрутизации есть понятие "шлюз по умолчанию" (default gateway). Фактически, наличие его означает следующее: "если не знаешь маршрута к адресу назначения, отправь его на шлюз по умолчанию".

Кроме маршрута по умолчанию роутер может знать и про конкретные подсети. Например, домашний роутер обычно знает только свою внутреннюю подсеть, к которой подключены устройства пользователя. Всё остальное он "кидает" на шлюз провайдера. Домашний роутер может также знать про внутреннюю сеть провайдера, но обычно на этом его "знания" заканчиваются.

А вот роутеры провайдеров "знают" гораздо больше. Если не вникать во внутреннюю маршрутизацию сети провайдера, то можно упрощённо сказать, что роутер провайдера знает про все внутренние подсети провайдера, а также про подсети других провайдеров, к которым у него есть прямые подключения (так называемый "пиринг"). Как ни странно, у большинства провайдеров тоже есть шлюз по умолчанию, который ведёт к провайдеру более высокого уровня и масштаба (так называемый "аплинк", uplink).

Но! На самой вершине сети находятся провайдеры из группы Tier-1. Их роутеры не имеют шлюза по умолчанию. Они "знают" где находится любой IP-адрес. Провайдеры Tier-1 и обеспечивают связность сети, т.е. позволяют соединиться между собой любым двум "белым" IP-адресам. Естественно, что оборудование этих провайдеров не идёт ни в какое сравнение с обычными домашними "железочками".

Следует добавить, что если мы знаем где находится адрес назначения, т.е. адрес роутера, за которым он находится, это не означает, что этот целевой роутер единственный. Фактически, с адресом роутера связывается подсеть, т.е. непрерывная группа адресов (или несколько групп), которые обслуживает этот роутер (так называемый "префикс"). За этим роутером может стоять группа других, каждый из которых обслуживает только часть этих адресов. Например, провайдер может ставить по маршрутизатору на район и иметь один общегородской, объединяющий районные подсети. Такая структура позволяет агрегировать адреса, уменьшая число префиксов на уровне аплинков.

Таким образом, когда ваш домашний компьютер в Волгограде хочет получить страницу с сайта в Мексике, он отправляет пакет на домашний роутер, тот - на маршрутизатор провайдера, провайдер - своему аплинку и так до тех пор, пока не пакет не доберётся до провайдера, который знает где находится мексиканский сайт (точнее, знает адрес роутера, за которым он находится). Далее пакет проходит ещё цепочку маршрутизаторов, за которыми находятся всё более мелкие подсети и, наконец, добирается до нужного сайта. Аналогичный процесс происходит и когда сайт отправляет вам ответ.

Comment: Я бы исключил Tier-1 из этого описания. Только запутывает. Провайдер просто отдает тому из связанных с ним кто ближе (или дешевле) к цели. т.е. на основе текущей записи маршрутизации. Тем более что масса трафика идет в пределах крупных точек обмена трафиком без участия тех, кого принято называть Tier-1

Comment: Что изначально пакет идет на роутер провайдера - это понятно. Но как эти роутеры понимают направление до Мексики. Там же промежутке может быть несколько тысяч роутеров. Если каждый роутер знает маршрут смежных с ним, т.е. если смежных с ним еще сотня роутеров, как он поймет в какой стороне Мексика? Т.е.,90 приведут в тупик, а только 10 потенциально могут достичь Мексики, а далее у этих 10-ти еще сотня ответвлений? Пакет же не может биться через все роутеры мира, чтобы достичь Мексики?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев Каждый роутер знает в каком направлении Мексика, причём знает точно. Точнее говоря, он точно знает, на какой роутер отослать пакет, чтобы он попал в Мексику. Но это знание может быть "расплывчатым" ("кидай в аплинк, там разберут!"), либо точным (префикс, connected). В конце концов по цепочке аплинков пакет дойдёт до точки, которая знает точное направление в Мексику. И в итоге пакет проходит не через все роутеры, а по строго определённому маршруту.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, не надо переоценивать количество маршрутизаторов в цепочках... в маршруте редко бывает больше 20—30 хупов, максимальное «нормальное» значение — 64, а принципиально максимальное для IP — 256, а никак не «тысячи».

Comment: @kff Правильно ли я понимаю, что логика следующая. С домашнего роутера пакет пошел на роутер провайдера. Тот проверяет ip адреса смежных с ним сетей. И если среди них не находит требуемого - отправляет дальше - на более главный провайдер (региональный или магистральный), а он уже знает IP-адреса всех роутеров мира?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев Да, именно так. Есть некоторые нюансы, но в целом такое представление верно.

Comment: @Fat-Zer *принципиально максимальное для IP — 256* Неверно. Максимальное значение TTL - действительно, 255 (байт, куда деваться), а вот хопов может быть и больше, ибо любой маршрутизатор имеет полное право делать с TTL маршрутизируемого пакета что угодно - отнять 1 (обычное действие) или больше (способ сделать маршрут дороже, разгрузить), не изменять (сокрытие из маршрута), и даже увеличить его (опасно для обычных маршрутизаторов, но вполне допустимо при NAT/PAT). Другой вопрос - где такой маршрут найти (что-то типа "правила шести рукопожатий")...

Answer (score 6):

> как роутер понимает через какие еще маршрутизаторы нужно пройти пакету, чтобы добраться до требуемого IP-адреса?

Никак. Это не его забота. Роутер определяет только следующий узел, через который формально достижим адрес назначения, на основании своих локальных маршрутов. А куда слать дальше - забота уже следующего узла.